# Problem with Play Store on Samsung Galaxy Note II: Play Store does not open

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I was a regular Galaxy SII user, recently moved to Galaxy Note-2 - so far so good, but since today, I am finding my Play Store application, is not working on Note-2 [*it was, earlier*], even from the PC, when I am trying to download an app via Google Play application, it says 'Installed', but actually nothing happens.

I click Play Store, the Home-screen comes back, Play Store is not activated.

Other than that, all are fine, Facebook, LinkedIn, SMS, Phone are healthy!!!

Can someone guide me please?

BTW the firmware as per KIES is "PDA:MB3 / PHONE:LL1 / CSC:MC1 (STS) and android is 4.1.2

Comment: Can you link a screenshot of what it looks like when you try to install something from your Note 2?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I tried this, and it worked: `Settings > Application manager > All > Options > Reset the application preferences`.